# For post request produces keyword type doesn't become response headers content-type

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have the next swagger spec

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: REST API
host: '127.0.0.1:9090'
basePath: /main
tags:
  - name: serv
schemes:
  - http
  - https
paths:
  /path/get:
    get:
      tags:
        - serv
      summary: ''
      operationId: get
      produces:
        - text/xml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
  /path/post:
    post:
      tags:
        - serv
      summary: ''
      operationId: post
      produces:
        - text/xml
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: ''
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

In swagger-ui, for example on https://editor.swagger.io/, for get request 
[image]

keyword produces: - text/xml - become Response headers content-type: text/xml, end response is parsered ok

but for post request 
[image]

Although it is indicated that the type of response text/xml, but an error "can't parse JSON" occurs and Response headers content-type: application/json

How to make the response headers content-type become text/xml?

Comment: If you run the cURL command from the second image in a command shell, what response does it return?

Comment: POST "http://127.0.0.1:9090/main/path/post" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "test"
Response - REST POST  . The problem is in the swagger ui interface, "can't parse JSON" occurs and Response headers content-type: application/json

Comment: This is because the response is neither JSON nor XML but plain text. Either change your server at 127.0.0.1:9090 to return proper JSON or XML, or update `produces` in your API definition to reflect the actual media type returned by your API (e.g. `text/plain`).

Comment: Yes, for this response, I will change the `produces` on  `text/plain`, in the curl it is visible,  correct header `-H "accept: text/plain"`, but in swagger UI same error as in the screenshot "can't parse JSON" occurs and Response headers content-type: application/json